# Что такое симметричное замыкание?

Tags: математика, множества, дискретная-математика

Всем привет, ни как не могу понять что такое симметричное замыкание?
Знаю что симметричное замыкание R является объединением R с его обратное отношением R , на некотором множестве R, но как и что с этим делать ни как не пойму. Спасибо

Немного дополнил вопрос для удобства.

Ну вот допустим у нас есть множество X = {1,2,3,4} и пусть определенно отношение на X как R = {(1,21),(2,32),(3,5)}, и как найти симметричное замыкание R? Если проводить аналогию с примером с рейсами и аэропортами то получается (как я понял) отношение будет {(1,21),(2,32),(3,5)} но это получается же композиция, а по определениям я понял что симметричное замыкание ни такое строгое как композиция, так как в определении есть слова "либо то либо это". Поэтому мне кажется я не совсем понимаю как использовать определения симметричного замыкания на множествах.

Comment: Ну а что именно вам непонятно? Просто пояснить — это опять повторить определение, но вам же не это нужно... Как вам помочь?

Comment: [Например, если X - это набор аэропортов, а xRy означает «есть прямой рейс из аэропорта x в аэропорт y», то симметричное замыкание R является соотношением «есть прямой рейс либо из x в y, либо из y в x». Или, если X - это множество людей, а R - отношение «родитель для», то симметричное замыкание R - это отношение «x - родитель или потомок y».Википедия](https://star-wiki.ru/wiki/Symmetric_closure)

Comment: @Harry Ну вот допустим у нас есть множество X = {1,2,3,4} и пусть определенно отношение на X как R = {(1,21),(2,32),(3,5)}, и как найти симметричное замыкание R? Если проводить аналогию с примером с рейсами и аэропортами то получается (как я понял) отношение будет {(1,21),(2,32),(3,5)} но это получается же композиция, а по определениям я понял что симметричное замыкание ни такое строгое как композиция,  так как в определении есть слова "либо то либо это". Поэтому мне кажется я не совсем понимаю как использовать определения симметричного замыкания на множествах.

Comment: Отношение на множестве. А какое же (1,21) на вашем множестве? 21 это никак не член множества...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас 21 или 32 ну никак не попадают в множество X, так что отношение R определено не на X. Но пусть X = {1,2,3,4,5}, R = {(1,2),(2,3),(3,5)}. Тогда симметричное замыкание — это R = {(1,2),(2,3),(3,5)} + обратные, т.е.

{(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(2,1),(3,2),(5,3)}

Comment: "У вас 21 или 32 ну никак не попадают в множество X, так что отношение R определено не на X. " Я если честно сам не понимаю как это так у меня получилось -_- ... Большое спасибо, теперь разобрался. А если не сложно подскажите как найти транзитивное замыкание из вашего примера?

Comment: Транзитивное — есть (1,2) и (2,3) и (3,5) — значит, можно замкнуть, добавив (1,5) (раз есть 1->2->3->5), (2,5) и (1,3). Вроде бы так...